# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Description

Tags: asp.net

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Description...

Can anyone help me ?  Please , It will be highly appreciated..
Here is my Dapper Code to insert the Description, Quantity, Cost and HSCode and only the Description Colume is not working saying insert the value NULL into column 'Description.

```
public void CreateIncomingShipmentLine(IncomingShipmentLine incomingShipmentLine)
{
    DbConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection(Constant.DatabaseConnection);
    _Connection.Open();

    // IncomingShipmentLine

    string myIncomingShipmentLineQuery = "INSERT INTO IncomingShipmentLine( Description, Quantity, Cost, HSCode) VALUES ( @Description, @Quantity, @Cost, @HSCode)";

    _Connection.Execute(myIncomingShipmentLineQuery, new
                                                     {
                                                         Description = incomingShipmentLine.Description,
                                                         Quantity = incomingShipmentLine.Quantity,
                                                         Cost = incomingShipmentLine.Cost,
                                                         HSCode = incomingShipmentLine.HSCode
                                                     });
    _Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `Description` column doesn't allow nulls and you actually provide such value in the `Description` property of the `incomingShipmentLine`. Either you should populate the object properly wth not-null value, or you should override the value to some empty string, or you should change your column to accept nulls.

Comment: Thank you so much - Jakub Szumiato, Its working ...... :) – Namaraj Giri

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISNULL` property before insert.

If it's `NULL` insert `empty` value instead of `NULL`, since your `Description` coulmn is `NOT NULL`

Try this

```
public void CreateIncomingShipmentLine(IncomingShipmentLine incomingShipmentLine)
{
    DbConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection(Constant.DatabaseConnection);
    _Connection.Open();

    // IncomingShipmentLine

    string myIncomingShipmentLineQuery = "INSERT INTO IncomingShipmentLine( Description, Quantity, Cost, HSCode) VALUES ( ISNULL(@Description,''), @Quantity, @Cost, @HSCode)";

    _Connection.Execute(myIncomingShipmentLineQuery, new
                                                     {
                                                         Description = incomingShipmentLine.Description,
                                                         Quantity = incomingShipmentLine.Quantity,
                                                         Cost = incomingShipmentLine.Cost,
                                                         HSCode = incomingShipmentLine.HSCode
                                                     });
    _Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: @NamarajGiri happy programming